# Angular dependency injection into an export function

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, module

I am using apollo graphql, and it has a module with a function inside of it.

```
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink, connectToDevTools: true){
```

Inside this function you define the url for the graphql endpoint `const uri = http://127.0.0.1/graphql` for instance.

I would like to import this url form a service (so that I only have to change the backend server url in one place), but I can not inject the service, for the property stays undefined.

```
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink, connectToDevTools: true, urlservice: UrlsService) {
    const uri = urlservice.graphqlAddress;
```

Error: `Cannot read property 'graphqlAddress' of undefined`

I have also tried injecting the service into the modules constructor, but this is even lower down the chain, with the same results.

How do I get an outside property into the function `createApollo`?

My service basically looks like this:

```
export class UrlsService {
    ...
    graphqlAddress = 'http://192.168.2.24:8000/graphql/';
    ...
}
```

GraphQLModule providers:

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
    providers: [
        UrlsService,
        {
            provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
            useFactory: createApollo,
            deps: [HttpLink],
        },
    ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {
}
```

Comment: How did you define the provider? You probably just need to add `UrlsService` as a dependency

Comment: @David With or without having the service in the module providers makes no difference, still the same error.

Comment: Can you show you providers declaration?

Comment: @David Soz, I have added it...

Comment: And with `deps: [HttpLink, UrlsService],` it does not work ? Also, your `connectToDevTools: true, ` looks like a mistake. Try removing it if it's always true, otherwise you need to provide it

Comment: @David Ok,it is working now! I had to put it at the `deps: [HttpLink, UrlsService]` as you said, did not know you can declare more dependencies there. If you want you can put it in an answer and I can mark it correct. What would you call that small provider object inside the providers? And why would it work there and not inside providers?  :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring a factory function that takes parameters, you need to declare these parameters in the dependency setting `deps` , in the providers config. (This is explained in the [angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#factory-providers-usefactory)). So in your example, you need to add `UrlsService`

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
    providers: [
        UrlsService,
        {
            provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
            useFactory: createApollo,
            deps: [HttpLink, UrlsService],
        },
    ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {
}
```

Also, the `connectDevTools` argument does not look like it's declared properly

```
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink, connectToDevTools: true, urlservice: UrlsService)
```