# 'typeof import is not assignable to type 'Provider'

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have multiple exports within single file like:

```
export class xyz {}, 
export class abc {},
export function fn1(){}
export function fn2(){}
```

like so. all it's nested inside of angular library. I am trying to export them all. for that i am try like this in module:

```
import * as sharedTools from './services/shared-service';
```

and adding in to provider:

`providers: [sharedTools],` - but getting error like this:

```
Type 'typeof import("/services/shared-service")' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type 'typeof import("/services/shared-service")' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: substitute wildcard with actual names of the export. Also check if you're using any private constructors in your service.

Comment: `substitute wildcard with actual names of the export` - how? can you show a sample?

Comment: I meant like this: `import { xyz, abc, fn1, fn2 } from './services/shared-service';`. What are signatures of the function defined in the service? Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52659398/6513921

Comment: Michael D, export function makes issue, getting like : 
`Type '(date?: any, dd?: any) => string' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type '(date?: any, dd?: any) => string' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.

(alias) function DateForServer(date?: any, dd?: any): string 
import DateForServer`

Answer (score 0):

[Non-class dependencies](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#non-class-dependencies) (like functions in this case) are exported as follows

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export const SampleFunctionService = Injectable() (function fn1() {
  console.log('function fn1');
});
```

Then import and provide it in the module:

```
import { SampleFunctionService} from './services/shared-service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    ...
    SampleFunctionService
  ],
})
```

Now it can be injected:

```
import { SampleFunctionService } from './services/shared-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  ...
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {   
  constructor(@Inject(SampleFunctionService) _sampleFunctionService) { }
```